# How to call a Delete from Website Button in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

im using Symfony for my Projekt and i want to have a Button near the Data where you can delete the entry from the Database.
Im tried using a twig extension but it feels like its not the right way to do that.
Any Ideas?

HTML

```
<script>
        function test() {
            {{ deleteTicket() }};
        }
    </script>

{% for form in myForm %}
        <h3>Task</h3>
        {{ form.data.text }}
        <h3>Priority</h3>
        {{ form.data.dropdown }}

        <button onclick="test()" class="btn btn-primary">delete</button>

    {% endfor %}
```

TWIG Extension

```
public function deleteTicket(DynamicRepository $formRepository)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $myForm = $formRepository->findBy(['creator' => $user]);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($myForm);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_form_data');
    }
```

Comment: could you please, attach how did you created the form?

Comment: Can't see the relevance of requesting that. OP is trying to run serverside code on the clientside and should either use `ajax` or create an actual route which is callable in order to delete the specific row. Pretty sure there are already multiple questions about this on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check the [symfony form docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers), you will see how to create correctly a form, how to add form fields, rendering and how to mange data.

I suggest you do this:

1 - [Create a form class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) with your inputs.

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('text', TextType::class)
            ->add('dropdown', DateType::class)
            ->add('delete', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

2 - [Render the form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#rendering-forms), this is something that you are currently doing.

3 - [Handle submitted data](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms) afer clicking delete button.

```
public function delete(Request $request): Response
    {
        // just set up a fresh $task object (remove the example data)
        $task = new Task();

        $form = $this->createForm(TaskType::class, $task);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
            // but, the original `$task` variable has also been updated
            $task = $form->getData();

            // your code to remove
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($task);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('task_success');
        }

        return $this->render('task/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```